# Unable to get hidden layer activation of ANN

Tags: python, theano, keras

I am using python2 and i'm trying to get the activations of hidden layer. I am using the following code which is giving me an error:

```
get_activations = theano.function([my_model.layers[0].input], my_model.layers[0].get_output(train=False),
                              allow_input_downcast=True)
```

When I run the code it says:

```
AttributeError: 'Dense' object has no attribute 'get_output'
```

I have tried to use `my_model.layers[0].output` which also does not work correctly.

What should I do to get the activations from a layer given?

Comment: Could you give us model definition and info which version of Keras do you use?

Comment: My Keras version is 1.0.3. and i have a 1 input 1 hidden and 1 output layer in my model. When I wrote this code I was using python3. Now i have loaded it in pycharm using py2, could this be an issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

attribute `get_output` is only defined for old versions of keras (0.3). It no longer exists in version 1.0.

[see new syntax (keras doc FAQ)](http://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-visualize-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer)

something like

```
get_activations = K.function([model.layers[0].input], [model.layers[1].output])
```

should work since the hidden layer is the second layer in your model (i.e. `model.layers[1]`)